# Animated SVG not loading correctly

Tags: javascript, wordpress, svg

My website http://spoleta.com/ has an animated SVG logo in the header that is being controlled by this JS

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 $(window).scroll(function() {
var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
    navbar = $('.x-navbar');

if (scrollPos > 1) {
  navbar.addClass('alt-color x-navbar-fixed-top');
   $('.x-brand img').attr('src','/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/spoleta_logo_reverse2.svg');
} else {
  navbar.removeClass('alt-color x-navbar-fixed-top');
  $('.x-brand img').attr('src','/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/spoleta_logo_forward.svg');
}
 });
   });
```

It works the first time you scroll up and down but then the animations seem to get "stuck". Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested your site on different browsers? I currently have the same issue with Version 67.0.3396.87 build of Chrome. Please inform me if it's the same with other browsers.